# Autowiring beans instantiated both individually and as list

Tags: spring

I have beans instantiated as below in a @Configuration

```
@Bean
public Queue queue1() {
  return new Queue("queue1");
}

@Bean
public Queue queue2() {
  return new Queue("queue2");
}

@Bean
public List<Queue> queues(List<String> names) {
  List<Queue> ret = new LinkedList<>();
  for (String name : names) {
    ret.add(new Queue(name));
  }
  return ret;
}
```

When I @Autowire them like below

```
@Autowired
private Collection<Queue> queues;
```

or

```
@Autowired
private List<Queue> queues;
```

I would expect to get all (both the ones instantiated individually and as 
a list) of them but I only get the ones instantiated individually.

Can you advise please?

**Note:**

If I use @Qualifier I can get the list ones to autowire but only those. I'm looking for a way to autowire them all.

Comment: What do you wanna achieve? This seems to be a bad idea for me.

Comment: @galovics I know the name of couple of the queues apriori but the rest of the names I get as a list. Then I want to iterate through all of them.

Comment: You should add them individually as beans. You should use a `BeanRegistryPostProcessor` or `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to do so. Exposing them as a list won't make then spring managed beans (the individual `Queue`s in there).

Comment: So are you calling this method public List<Queue> queues(List<String> names){..} manually from your code . If so then there is no point in declaring as @Bean. Spring cannot autowire it in such cases

Comment: @pvpkiran No, I'm not calling it manually. The code is called by the spring framework because of the `@Bean` annotation.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum that's helpful. Are you saying the only way to instantiate multiple beans (that will be exposed as inidividual beans) is by using a BeanRegistryPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor ?

Comment: I know it will be called because of @Bean but It's called with what argument? What is the names which are passed to this function?

Comment: @pvpkiran that's an autowired parameter no problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you write a proper answer that I can accept as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to obtain what I needed using `PostConstruct`:

```
@Autowired
private QueueNames queueNames;

@Autowired
private ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void queues() {
  for (String name : queueNames.get()) {
    beanFactory.registerSingleton(name, new Queue(name));
  }
}
```